# How to allow pinch zoom and swipe in bootstrap carousel?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

I'm using [Bootstrap Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/carousel/#how-it-works) and i have a problem on mobile which is that i can't pinch zoom and use swipe gesture at the same time in the image of the carousel only if i deactivated the swipe. How can i allow pinch zoom and swipe in bootstrap carousel ?

I tried to add the following css but it's not working :

```
.carousel.pointer-event {
  touch-action: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.carousel.pointer-event {
  touch-action: pan-y pinch-zoom;
}
```